# What is the best strategy to store objects ensuring unique name and being able to efficiently retrieve them later, in c++?

Tags: c++, containers, std, replace

I'm coding a Composite class (similar to `QObject` of Qt) and at the moment I'm storing the children in a `std::vector`.
Each Composite instance has a name and this name has to be unique between all the other instances that are siblings of this one, or probably better said, between the instances that share the same parent.

Each time a new instance is pushed inside the `vector`, I must look if its name is already used by one of the instances already in the `vector`, if it does, I must change its name adding a number.

The code I came up with is quite silly and very slow when the number of children become consistent.

here is the class:

```
class Composite
{
public:
    Composite(const std::string &name, Composite *ancestor=NULL);
    ~Composite();

private:
    std::string name;
    Composite *ancestor;
    std::vector<Composite*> descendants;

public:
    void setName(const std::string &name);
};
```

this is the constructor and `setName` implementation:

```
Composite::Composite(const std::string &name, Composite *ancestor)
{
    this->ancestor = ancestor;
setName(name);
if (ancestor!=NULL)
    ancestor->descendants.push_back(this);

}
```

.

```
void Composite::setName(const std::string &name)
{
    this->name = name;

    if (ancestor!=NULL)
    {
        CompositeList::iterator dIt;
        for( dIt=ancestor->descendants.begin(); dIt!=ancestor->descendants.end(); dIt++)
        {
            if ((*dIt)==this)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (this->name == (*dIt)->getName())
            {
                 int trailingNumber = stringToInt(getTrailingNumber(this->name));
                 std::string cleanName = removeTrailingNumber(this->name);
                 this->name = cleanName+intToString(trailingNumber+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might be fine for very few children, but when they become hundreds then the `setName` function really become slow.
Imagine this situation:

```
Composite *parent = new Composite("pippo");

for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
    Composite("ClashingName", parent);
}
```

the first time is fine, the second time the name is changed in ClashingName0, the third time the name is firstly cahnged into ClashingName0, than it find the clashing with the second instance and set the name to ClashingName1... you got the idea, it is exponential, when it comes at the end of that loop an unacceptable amount of time is passed by.

So the real problem here is how to efficiently find the name clashing and efficiently assign a new name that is not already used?
Any std container is fine for me and my compiler support C++11, but I can't/want to use Boost because the project I'm working on is incredibly small (it is basically this class)

I'm not exactly a seasoned user of C++, I was thinking to use `map` or `unordered_map` but I'm really hungry for experts' suggestions here.

Comment: Yeah, unordered_map would work perfectly for your needs here.

Comment: I think your `setName()` is missing `this->name = name`.

Comment: Why not instead have the name generated by the parent itself, or by `Composite`'s constructor? If you must have a "friendly name", you can take a string from the user and combine it with a system-generated token that should be unique.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for spotting that, I have corrected the mistake

Comment: @Rook I wouldn't use names at all if I could, but it is a requirement unfortunately. Users of this class want to be able to get any child by name and that name has to be exactly what they want, except for the appended number.

Comment: @DanNiero: the "except for" bit rather renders their naming scheme a bit useless. How can they tell which "foo" item in a collection of siblings is theirs? A centralised ID generating mechanism might help... `std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> make_id_pair(const std::string& nonunique_id)` sort of thing. Make them generate and remember an application-unique ID, and have your `Composite` throw an error if fed an ID structure that is already in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you need to change the way your objects are stored. Something like the following:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Composite> >
```

The key to the map is the prefix, and the index in the vector is the nth `Composite` object. You would need to provide a custom lookup function which split the passed in name.. e.g.

```
std::string query = "pipo_10";
```

In your lookup function,

```
Composite* lookup(std::string const& key)
{
  // split the key to get the prefix and the index
  // lookup in the map using the prefix
  // return the index
}
```

EDIT 1: To save all the string operations, you could define your own *custom key*, which is simply a pair (e.g, `std::pair<std::string, int>` which is the prefix and the index), and your lookup would simply use the values from this *key*.

<strike>EDIT 2: Thinking about this a little more, better to have a map of map, e.g.</strike>

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<int, Composite> >
```

Now instead of the index being an index in the vector, it's a lookup in the second map. This handles deletions better, the key will be the composite key as I said before (the pair).

Crediting @Steves' suggestion..

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, int>, Composite>
```

Use the `lower_bound()` trick to locate the last index for the given `Composite`

Comment: +1, but I prefer the `pair` as key over the map of vectors. I doubt that you want the names of all the `k+1 ... n` children to change if you delete the `k`th child from a set of `n` siblings, but nor would you want to have to arrange a scheme so that the vector can have "deleted" elements in the middle.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I was thinking about that, how would you locate the next index for a given prefix though (without counting all matching prefixes - which could be tricky)? May be it's better to have a map of map where the index in the second map is the nth `Composite`, true about the deleted `Composite` objects.. let me update..

Comment: `descendents.lower_bound(make_pair(prefix, INT_MAX))` finds a suitable slot to add a new descendent whose desired name is `prefix`. It doesn't re-use any slots that have been vacated, unless they happen to be at the end. If removal happens a lot then you could upgrade the `int` to `long long` to avoid ever overflowing.

Comment: @SteveJessop, smart, didn't think of that!!

Comment: I accepted this one as answer but it could have been as well Steve's. Both Nim and Steve helped me a lot here. I end up using a combination of your suggestions. I'm sure my code has room for improvment, but it is so much better than before

Answer (score 1):

Either `map` or `unordered_map` will do the job, use the `count` function to test whether a name is in the map or not, and the `find` function or `operator[]` to access it.

`unordered_map` is likely to be a bit faster overall.

`map` can deal better with your nasty `"ClashingName"` example, because you can use `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` to find the last clashing name in a single lookup, rather than looking up each of `ClashingName0` ... `ClashingName9999` in turn.

Beware that `map` by default sorts in lexicographical order, so `ClashingName10` comes before `ClashingName9`. There are also problems to do with what happens when someone provides you with a name that has digits in it, especially at the end.

Fix this with Nim's suggestion -- use a pair of `string, int` as the map key, and construct the name from that pair as required. Again, you have to do something special when someone supplies you with a name that ends in digits. Make sure that the name `"Clash10"` can't occur twice, once as `("Clash", 10)` and again as `("Clash1", 0)`. A simple option is to forbid one character from the provided name, and use that as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an additional map per object, you could do the following:

```
// inside Composite definiton
std::map<std::string, int> names_of_descendants;
```

Then simply:

```
void Composite::setName(const std::string &name)
{
    if (ancestor)
    {
        // for the first usage of certain name, map's operator[]
        // will insert default constructed int (0) in the map
        this->name = name + ancestor->names_of_descendants[name];

        // increment the value for this name, for the next call of setName
        ++names_of_descendants[name];
    }
}
```

You can keep the vector for storing descendants.